# Selecting a Distinct MAX NoteID for Individual Users

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am attempting to generate a query in SQL Server with multiple JOIN statements that provides the latest noteid for a Talent (aka users) in our database along with a few other datapoints like the talents name, category, status, division, and followupdate in my query.

So far I have tried the following query but I continue to receive multiple records for the same Talents.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(n.NoteID) as Note, 
    t.FirstName, t.LastName, s.Name AS Status, 
    tc.Name AS Category, d.Name, n.FollowUpDate AS FollowUpDate
FROM 
    Notes n
JOIN 
    TalentNotes tn ON n.NoteID = tn.NoteID
JOIN 
    Talents t ON t.TalentID = tn.TalentID
JOIN 
    TalentStatuses s ON s.TalentStatusID = t.TalentStatusID
JOIN 
    TalentCategories tc ON tc.TalentCategoryID = t.TalentCategoryID
JOIN 
    Divisions d ON d.DivisionID = t.DivisionID
WHERE 
    tc.Name = 'G1'
    AND t.EmailAddress NOT LIKE '%x3%'
    OR tc.Name = 'X1'
    AND t.EmailAddress NOT LIKE '%x3%'
GROUP BY 
    t.FirstName, t.LastName, s.Name, tc.Name, d.name, n.FollowUpDate
```

Results:

[image]

Ultimately I would like to see a table that shows me distinct talent with the MAX NoteID but currently I continue to receive multiple different NoteID's for the same talent. Any help in accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server (SSMS). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you show us the result with the duplicates you're trying to eliminate?

Comment: Do you have another repeating value when you see talent doubles such as d.Name?

Comment: Probably you have too many columns in the group by. How do you uniquely identify talent?

Comment: @Thermos - Just added an image of the results I receive from the query I have.

Comment: @RossBush - yes, please see image I just attached as a reference to the results. Thanks!

Comment: @Piotr - Talent are uniquely ID with a TalentID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.NoteId, A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.Status, A.Category, A.Name, A.FollowUpDate
FROM (
SELECT n.NoteId, t.FirstName, t.LastName, s.Name as Status, tc.Name as Category, d.Name, n.FollowUpDate as FollowUpDate, 
row_number() over (partition by t.FirstName, t.LastName order by n.NoteId DESC) rnk
    FROM Notes n
    JOIN TalentNotes tn ON n.NoteID=tn.NoteID
    JOIN Talents t ON t.TalentID=tn.TalentID
    JOIN TalentStatuses s ON s.TalentStatusID=t.TalentStatusID
    JOIN TalentCategories tc ON tc.TalentCategoryID=t.TalentCategoryID
    JOIN Divisions d ON d.DivisionID=t.DivisionID
    WHERE tc.Name = 'G1'
    AND t.EmailAddress NOT LIKE '%x3%'
    OR tc.Name = 'X1'
    AND t.EmailAddress NOT LIKE '%x3%')A
    where A.rnk = 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Sorry I am a newby to SQL and I really appreciate everyone's help and especially @GenWan .

Answer (score 0):

Try removing follupdate from the group by:

```
SELECT MAX(n.NoteID) as Note, t.FirstName, t.LastName, s.Name as Status, tc.Name as Category, d.Name
FROM Notes n
JOIN TalentNotes tn ON n.NoteID=tn.NoteID
JOIN Talents t ON t.TalentID=tn.TalentID
JOIN TalentStatuses s ON s.TalentStatusID=t.TalentStatusID
JOIN TalentCategories tc ON tc.TalentCategoryID=t.TalentCategoryID
JOIN Divisions d ON d.DivisionID=t.DivisionID
WHERE tc.Name = 'G1'
AND t.EmailAddress NOT LIKE '%x3%'
OR tc.Name = 'X1'
AND t.EmailAddress NOT LIKE '%x3%'
GROUP BY t.FirstName, t.LastName, s.Name, tc.Name, d.name
```

Comment: I attempted this query and it seems to work, however, I do need to display what the n.followupdate is for that specific MAX n.noteid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine how you want to handle the followup date. As it stands, it is being grouped by so you will have one row per distinct date alongside other group members.

Maybe:

```
MAX(n.FollowUpDate) as FollowUpDate
```

Comment: When I remove the group by for n.FollowUpDate I recieve an error message "Column 'Notes.FollowUpDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: If you want to display the MAX/MIN FollowUpDate and only want one per talent then it must be in the GROUP BY, else you should remove it from your output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like grouping by Follow Up date is what's messing you up. I would suggest getting the max note ID for each talent in a CTE, and then selecting the columns you want and joining to the CTE:

```
WITH Max_Note AS (
    SELECT MAX(n.NoteID) AS NoteID, tn.TalentID
    FROM Notes n
    JOIN TalentNotes tn ON n.NoteID=tn.NoteID
    GROUP BY tn.TalentID
)
SELECT n.NoteID as Note, t.FirstName, t.LastName, s.Name as Status, tc.Name as Category, d.Name, n.FollowUpDate as FollowUpDate
FROM Max_Note n
JOIN TalentNotes tn ON n.NoteID=tn.NoteID
JOIN Talents t ON t.TalentID=tn.TalentID
JOIN TalentStatuses s ON s.TalentStatusID=t.TalentStatusID
JOIN TalentCategories tc ON tc.TalentCategoryID=t.TalentCategoryID
JOIN Divisions d ON d.DivisionID=t.DivisionID
WHERE tc.Name = 'G1'
AND t.EmailAddress NOT LIKE '%x3%'
OR tc.Name = 'X1'
AND t.EmailAddress NOT LIKE '%x3%'
```